# Print documents directly by click on button in activereport vb2015

Tags: vb.net

Im using active report 12 with vb2015

What im looking for is to print the document without showing the report screen

Please any help..

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
PrintExtension.Print(report.Document`)
```

You can refer here -> https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/print-without-viewing

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..   the code is working perfectly but show me the print dialog .. i wang it print without showing me the printdialog .. i want print with the default printer

Comment: @MohamedEsehaim

 mainReport.Document.Printer.PrinterName = "Printer Name"

PrintExtension.Print(report.Document,false,false,false);